# Does $\int e^\frac 1x \, \mathrm dx$ has a closed form?

Tags: calculus, integration

How can i solve the integral $\int e^\frac 1x \, \mathrm dx$?

I came across this one while trying to do multiple integral on $\int\int_D e^{(\frac xy)} \, \mathrm dA$ where D is the area between $y=1$ and $y=\sqrt x$

I know i solve this question by doing $\int^1_0 dy\int^{y^2}_0(e^{\frac xy}dx)$. But i don't like 'skipping' a possible solution , Any guidelines?

Comment: I don't think $\int e^{1/x} dx $ has an elementary anti-derivative, so I think your approach is the only realistic approach possible.

Comment: Instead try to do the integral with the limits $\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$ instead. This will lead to an integral you can sovle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is not elementary.  But Maple provides a closed form in terms of an "exponential integral" function:
$$
\int \!{{\rm e}^{{z}^{-1}}}{dz}=z{{\rm e}^{{z}^{-1}}}+{\rm Ei}_1 \left(-{z}^{-1} \right)
$$
The definition:
$$
{\rm Ei}_a \left(z \right) =\int _{1}^{\infty }\!{{\rm e}^{-tz}}{t}^{
-a}{dt}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute $z=1/x$ then you get $\int (-z^{-2} e^z) dz$, which can be solved using integrating by parts (x2).

Comment: While integrating by parts, at some step you'll get $\int e^z\ln zdz$ How do you proceed from there @Lucozade?

Comment: If you integrate by parts once, you get to something like $Ei(z)$, a 'special function'.

Comment: Yes, solution is in terms of exponential integral function Ei(), which is tabulated. Integral of that function, you will need to term by term, after expanding Ei() in a series.